# Firebase: Query by nearest location

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

Firebase can store documents with Geopoint object. https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/firestore/GeoPoint

But we can't use range filter on different fields and this is necessary for location querying.

As I understand year ago there was functionality to make such queries using Geofire
[Query for nearby locations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43357990/query-for-nearby-locations?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa)

But now it is obsolete and not working.

What is current solution?

Answer (score 3):

You can query using `GeoPoint` Firestore objects and `GreatherThan` clause together with `LessThan`. You should add your own accuracy to instead of use just one mile of distance.

```
fun Query.getNearestLocation(latitude: Double, longitude: Double, distance: Double): Query {
    // ~1 mile of lat and lon in degrees
    val lat = 0.0144927536231884
    val lon = 0.0181818181818182

    val lowerLat = latitude - (lat * distance)
    val lowerLon = longitude - (lon * distance)

    val greaterLat = latitude + (lat * distance)
    val greaterLon = longitude + (lon * distance)

    val lesserGeopoint = GeoPoint(lowerLat, lowerLon)
    val greaterGeopoint = GeoPoint(greaterLat, greaterLon)

    val docRef = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance().collection("locations")
    return docRef
            .whereGreaterThan("location", lesserGeopoint)
            .whereLessThan("location", greaterGeopoint)
}
```

This code is a Kotlin translation from the code made by Ryan Lee on [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46630507/how-to-run-a-geo-nearby-query-with-firestore?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa)

Comment: what about this issue.  All the documents we get are within the lat range, but not within the lon range https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46630507/how-to-run-a-geo-nearby-query-with-firestore?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa#comment85444540_46920982