# Designing a places directory in Firebase Realtime Database

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm working on an app that has a map with places displayed as pins.

I use Google Maps SDK to display the map. And I store the list of places (with a title, description, coords, etc) in Firebase Realtime Database.

Is there any way to load not the whole database of places but only the ones that can be shown on the screen with given scale (with clustering support when the map is too zoomed out). Or maybe Realtime Database isn't the one for me in this case and I should try something else?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand, but it sounds like you want to query the database to only return the places in a certain area. If so, have a look at GeoFire, which is made precisely for that: https://github.com/firebase/geofire-objc (and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43357990/query-for-nearby-locations).

Comment: Thank you! That's exactly what I've been looking for