# Fetch between values in Firebase database

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, latitude-longitude

Working with react native, I want to fetch places in a specific area.
In the Firebase databse I have the filed "longitude" and the field "latitude".

What I'm doing now does not work:

```
database()
   .ref()
   .child('places')
   .orderByChild('longitude')
   .startAt(min_longitude)
   .endAt(max_longitude)
   .then(fetchResp => {
      return fetchResp.json();
    })
   .then(fetchJsonResp => {
      resolve(fetchJsonResp);
   })
```

Any idea? What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Add ur database

Comment: In addition to seeing your database, it would also help to know what doesn't work about this code. It's typically easiest to see that if you `console.log()` the relevant values, then include the output you get in your question, as well as the output you're looking for.

Comment: In general though, to [query for nearby nodes with the Firebase Realtime Database](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bfirebase-realtime-database%5D+query+nearby), you'll want to use GeoFire: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43357990/query-for-nearby-locations/43358909#43358909

Answer (score 0):

The query correct is this one:

```
database()
   .ref()
   .child('places')
   .orderByChild('longitude')
   .startAt(min_longitude)
   .endAt(max_longitude)
   .once('value')
   .then(fetchResp => {
      return fetchResp.json();
    })
   .then(fetchJsonResp => {
      resolve(fetchJsonResp);
   })
```

the `.once('value')` was missing.

Comment: I'm parsing first the longitude on the db and from them filter the elements in latitude. If there is a way to fetch it directly to the db I would like to know.