# Firebase messaging: subscribed topics with Location Triggered Notifications

Tags: android, push-notification, geolocation, firebase-cloud-messaging, geospark

I'm using firebase cloud messaging and its notification mechanism
I've the following scenario, can you please help?
My android application allows its users to subscribe to interests (like running,movies,RESTAURANT): by using Firebase messaging topics mechanism

If any user creates a RESTAURANT event for example, I want that only nearby users within a radius (example 10km) receive a notification that a RESTAURANT event has been created.

The problem is that Firebase topics don't allow a filtering on locations. It send the notification to any user subsribed to RESTAURANT topics. Segments logic didn't allow the subscription mechanism
I've spend long days and hours on the topic: geofence and geofire aren't the direct solution or may be I did misunderstood.

I'd explored geospark but it's very expensive. Any idea how to solve this .  thank you?

Answer (score 1):

There is nothing built into Firebase Cloud Messaging to geo-target users. You will have to either use a third-party solution that builds this functionality on top of FCM, or you will have to build your own solution.

A good starting point for building your own would be to have a look at GeoFire, a library that adds geo-querying capabilities on top of Firebase's Realtime Database.

For more info see:

- The [GeoFire github repo](https://github.com/firebase/geofire-js)
- The [blog post](https://firebase.googleblog.com/2014/06/geofire-20.html) announcing GeoFire
- [Query for nearby locations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43357990/query-for-nearby-locations/43358909#43358909)

Comment: thank you Frank ,that's what I thought about , I'll do it myself so !