# How to perform some calculations in firebase realtime database before fetching data and fetch data accordilngly

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, flutter-layout

[image: Database sturucture]

I have a realtime database working with flutter app in frontend.Here with latitiude and longitudes data of different people.

**I want to read this data in a way that I only fetch the data(longitude & longitude) of the person who is atmost 100 meters away from the user.I am gonna have a large number of data in my database.**

One way I can use is to fetch all the data in my flutter app and filter accordingly by doing calculations using haversine formula on the app itself (but I guess that would be too inieffcient).

Is there a way to do calculations in the database and fetch only the data which is needed i.e only the coordinates that are atmost 100 meters away.

**In other words I want to apply the haversine formula in the backend itself and fetch only the data which gives result less than 100.**

OR do I need to change my approach.

I am new to flutter and firebase.Any help will be appreciated.

**I have tried using filtered and sorted queries but I couldn't persorm calculations on the backend by using them**

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43357990/query-for-nearby-locations. Note that distance is not something that can be calculated on the database server, so you will have to determine the range of results you want to get back and use that in a GeoFire query.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use a geocoder. Pass a persons lat/long as the center point of a 50 meter radius boundary. Then, query for all people (by lat/long) within the bounds of that radius.

You can do this using the [geofire package](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/solutions/geoqueries) with Cloud Firestore.

Alternatively, you could write a Firebase Function and use [node-geocoder](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-geocoder) in a very similar manner.

There are several Flutter geocoder plugins as well. I have not used these Flutter plugins but the procedure is almost identical based on their docs.

Comment: The geofire package that is used in that solution for Firestore was actually made for the Realtime Database, so it works with that too :)